# How to fast reorder child elements in flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, flex4

I have a control which contains many child elements (about 1000), and I need to sort them.

Now I doing that like this:

```
_elements.sortOn(...);

for (var i: int = 0; i < _elements.length; i++) {
    setItemIndex(_childItems[_elements[i].id], i);
}
```

- _childElement - object that contains UI-child elements, which i need to sort (key of the dictionary is an identifier from data-object
- _elements - array contains data-objects

But this is too slow! 
How to reorder the childs by my criteria as fast as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough info to be sure my answer is correct but... if "_elements" is an arraycollection and it's bound to the control as dataprovider

somethink like < ns:mycontrol dataProvider="{_elements}"/>

each time you change "_elements" the binding makes the control parse and render the data in the dataprovider, so, for a list 1000+ long it's going to be painful.

in this case I'd storethe _elements array (the data of the array collection) in a tmp variable and replace it with a new blank array. then do all your sorting stuff on the tmp and set it back again as the _elements data. by doing this you're just forcing parsing and rendering twice...not 1000+ times :)

my 2 cents,
ciao

Comment: i've updated question. I dont use dataprovider. I add item to group with addElement and store pointer to this object in _childItems

Comment: ok, so what you're doing in the for loop is evaluating the data object and setting the item index of the visual object in a group....
what I still don't get is: are you moving each visual object in the group's display list (slow way) or are you setting the index of the visual object inside an array then removing all visual objects from the group's display list and adding them again from the sorted array?